# how to display all hyperlinks from div tag in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe content like this

```
 <div id="some">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="sdfds">asdfsdf</a></li>
     <li><a href="sdfds">asdfdsf</a></li>
     <li><a href="sdfds">sdfgdfg</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I want to extract all these hyperlinks so that i can push these in database. One more thing i am extracting these links from iframe site. So far I tried these

```
var heading = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").find("h3").find(".hidetitle").html();
var link_address= $link.attr('href');
```

This was for the one link but i want to extract all the links thanks.

Comment: undefined variable:  frametest, eod-topbox, h3, hidetitle,$link.. Please paste the whole html structure. I am not able to find any link with given html structure...

Comment: Where does the iframe content come from? same website or another website?

Comment: it's from another website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
var aTags= $("a", "#some");
var array = new Array();
$.each(aTags, function(index, item) {
     array.push($(item).attr('href'));
});
```

When you works with iframes:

```
$("#if").on("load", function() {
    var frame = document.getElementById("if");
    var aTags = $('a', frame.contentWindow.document||frame.contentDocument);
    var array = new Array();
    $.each(aTags, function(index, item) {
        array.push($(item).attr('href'));
    });
    alert(array.length);
});
```

Where "if" is Frame's ID.

Comment: above code is in iframe so please give another answer.thanks in advance

Comment: I updaded my answer, please check it.